# Search for non-nested nodes with specific attribute set

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

The short long of it is I'm working on a small library in javascript that will replace <div src="somesite"></div> with the content from the specified source. This would allow coders to create dynamic pages without having to do more work server-side without the annoyance of using iframes.

What I need is an efficent way to get the top most div nodes of a branch with an src attribute. E.G:

```
<div src="somesite/pagelet.htm" id="div1">
    <div src="somesite/fallback.htm" id="div2"></div>
</div>
<div src="somesite/pagelet2.htm" id="div3"></div>
```

I want to retrieve #div1 and #div3 and ignore #div2 until later. At the moment I'm using the following function, but am wondering if there is a more efficent way to do this:

```
function getRootElementsByAttribute(rootEle, tag, attr) {
    try {
        tag = tag.toLowerCase();
        if (rootEle.tagName.toLowerCase() === tag && rootEle.hasAttribute(attr)) {
            return [rooEle]
        }
        var eles = rootEle.getElementsByTagName(tag),
            nodes = [], ele, isRoot, eleParent, a;

        for (a=0; a<eles.length; a++) {
            ele = eles[a];
            if (ele.hasAttrinute(attr)) {
                isRoot = true;
                eleParent = ele;
                while ((eleParent = eleParent.parentNode)) {
                    if (eleParent.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div' && eleParent.hasAttribute(attr)) {
                        isRoot = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isRoot == true) nodes.push(ele)
            }
        }
    }catch(e){}
    return nodes;
}
```

Please no answers suggesting the use of a library. It seems overkill to import a whole library when all it would be used for is this single function

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use an XPath expression to get all root divs with the attribute source using something like the following XPath expression:

```
/div[@src]
```

/div selects all divs that are on the root level. For all divs in the document use //div.
[@src] specifies that you only want nodes with the 'src' attribute.

```
var xmlDoc = //load your document here
var xpath  = "/div[@src]"
var nodes  = xmlDoc.evaluate(xpath, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);
```

Comment: The problem is that `incude(NodeHere)`, where NodeHere can be any node in the DOM tree, causes an XPath error or returns null.